# Put a grey background behind code extracts in a Latex document (like this site does)

Tags: listings, backgrounds

I'm using the `listings` user package to insert extracts of code into my document, however it isn't distinct enough from the normal text as I'd like. Is there a way to put a grey background behind the code extracts, like the ones used on this site?

e.g:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Also/alternatively, can I indent the code, so the areas of code have wider margins?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The key `backgroundcolor` of the `lstlisting` is what you are looking for for the colored background. To indent a bit the code, play with `xleftmargin` and `framexleftmargin` to fit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
Test

\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray},
                   language = C,
                   xleftmargin = 2cm,
                   framexleftmargin = 1em]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: might be an idea to crop the image before uploading it (I have exactly the same problem each time)

Comment: @daleif I am using `\pagestyle{empty}` and `pdfcrop` tool for that task.

Comment: @Malipivo good point, but what arguments do you give to pdfcrop?

Comment: I usually just take a screen grab, open it in gimp and crop it. Then I don't have to alter the original source

Comment: @cjorssen It is worth one small question at TeX.SX. `:-)` I usually pass only `--hires --margins 3` to the `pdfcrop` tool.

Comment: In an application of mine, `backgroundcolor` only started to work when I moved it to the end of the argument list; this may be a recurrent issue.

Comment: @cjorssen when I use only `backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}` it does not cover long line. see [this image](https://imgur.com/a/CVsa8)  `\lstinputlisting[float,lineno=left,backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}]{config.xml}`

Comment: Why are there thin white horizontal lines through the background colour?

Answer (score 11):

I've been playing around with different options and I found another way to do it. I'll add it here as an alternative suggestion.

This looks very similar to the style used on the stackexchange sites.

```
%Put in the header

\usepackage{listings} %code extracts
\usepackage{xcolor} %custom colours
\usepackage{mdframed} %nice frames

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95} %the shade of grey that stack exchange uses

%Put in the main document

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=light-gray, roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15, outerlinewidth=1, linecolor=light-gray]
\begin{lstlisting}
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
      printf("Hello world!\n");
      return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
```

Comment: +1 for using a background colour that actually looks nice.

Answer (score 6):

Here's yet another solution using `tcolorbox (version 3.02)`.

The first variant is breakable and uses the full line width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,listings,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{breakable,listing only,
  listing options={language=c,aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt},
  size=fbox,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,arc=0pt,colback=lightgray}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second variant is not breakable, but the gray background adapts to the code width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,listings,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{hbox,listing only,
  listing options={language=c,aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt},
  size=fbox,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,arc=0pt,colback=lightgray}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]