# Format Code/Pseudocode

Tags: formatting, pseudocode

In a document containing a lot of other stuff, I have the following code which I have kept in verbatim(for lack of other ideas). As you can see, the alignment doesn't look so good.[image]
 How do I make it more presentable, so that it becomes more readable, with indentation perhaps(verbatim doesnt seem to handle spaces and tabs)?

```
\documentclass[]{article}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{verbatim}    

    if (n == 0 || n == 1){    
    return n;        
    }        
    j = 0;    
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){      
    if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){        
    arr[j] = arr[i];       
    j++;      
    }       
    }      
    arr[j++] = arr[n-1];      


\end{verbatim}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @DG' Is it more readable now? I wanna know how I could present it in a Latex Document, not on tex.stackexchange.

Comment: Do you want LaTeX to indent it for you? It isn't the right tool for the job. There are editors out there that will support the programming language and will have auto-indentation for it, so why not using one of those?

Comment: @TeXnician, I am aware of code formatting tools and IDEs. If you see the screenshot attached, the code isnt indented well. This is part of my larger document. I believe you have misunderstood my question.

Comment: Well what I see in your screenshot is some verbatim code which you claim that one would see to be badly aligned. I do not get which kind of more readability you want. Making it stand out from ordinary text (maybe listings would help here) or making it nice in itself (external code formatting might be the way to go). Also your claim that verbatim can't handle spaces or tabs is wrong.

Comment: `lsitings` package! But maybe I am missing something in your question?

Comment: Have a look at [algorithmicx](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) for pseudocode and [minted](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) for code.

Comment: @TeXnician I have provided a MWE. As you can see, If is not indented inside the For loop where it is nested. Please tell me how to place spaces here. I would really appreciate an example.

Comment: See my answer for that…

Comment: For the automatic indenting you need to call an external tool, as neither `listings` or `minted` provides such functionality as far as I know. This can be done from within LaTeX with a (medium) bit of trouble. Which operating system do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{myListingStyle} 
    {
        basicstyle = \small\ttfamily,
        breaklines = true,
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    style = myListingStyle,
    caption = {Nice listing.}
    ]
    if (n == 0 || n == 1){    
        return n;        
    }        
    j = 0;    
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){      
        if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){        
            arr[j] = arr[i];       
            j++;      
        }       
    }      
    arr[j++] = arr[n-1]; 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See [Put a grey background behind code extracts in a Latex document (like this site does)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176966) for example for adding a background color. It's also possible to load the code from an external file -- just have a look at related questions.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the caption for listings?

Comment: @GermanShepherd Yes, just have a look at the code and remove `caption = {Nice listing.}`.

Answer (score 9):

### Verbatim

Contrary to what you claim in your question, verbatim supports spaces and indentation, so why not use it?

[image: verbatim]

```
\documentclass[]{article}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{verbatim}
    if (n == 0 || n == 1){    
      return n;        
    }        
    j = 0;    
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){      
      if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){        
        arr[j] = arr[i];       
        j++;      
      }       
    }      
    arr[j++] = arr[n-1];
\end{verbatim}    
\end{document}
```

### Listings

The `listings` package can add colors.

[image: listings]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,language=c,keywordstyle=\color{blue}}
\begin{document}    
\begin{lstlisting}
    if (n == 0 || n == 1){    
      return n;        
    }        
    j = 0;    
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){      
      if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){        
        arr[j] = arr[i];       
        j++;      
      }       
    }      
    arr[j++] = arr[n-1];
\end{lstlisting}    
\end{document}
```

### Minted

The `minted` package is even more powerful…

[image: minted]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}    
\begin{minted}{c}
    if (n == 0 || n == 1){    
      return n;        
    }        
    j = 0;    
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){      
      if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){        
        arr[j] = arr[i];       
        j++;      
      }       
    }      
    arr[j++] = arr[n-1];
\end{minted}    
\end{document}
```

### Tcblisting

You can of course combine it with tcolorbox or something else…

[image: tcblisting]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{mylisting}{listing only,listing engine=minted, minted language=c,colback=gray!20}
\begin{document}    
\begin{mylisting}
if (n == 0 || n == 1){    
  return n;        
}        
j = 0;    
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){      
  if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){        
    arr[j] = arr[i];       
    j++;      
  }       
}      
arr[j++] = arr[n-1];
\end{mylisting}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Very complete answer :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner By far not, but listing some common options :)

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by others, `verbatim` does work for code (I use it for that purpose). The issue you see is that you usually format your code with tabs which `verbatim` is ignoring for some reason. So what I do is I put my code into `verbatim` select it and replace tabs with say 4 (or any number for that matter) of spaces (but just inside the selection).

Comment: Are you sure that `verbatim` does not support tabs? In my case, it does.

Comment: i wrote a 80page script About the use of a finite element Analysis program that included a LOT of example Code with tabs. and i had to replace them all because else my Output would look like the one that the OP shared. this may depend on the tex Distribution however.