# How to insert (C/C++) code into my document with a grey background?

Tags: color, code

I am using the `listings` package to insert code from files into my .tex document like shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21344989/4647107
I have instances in my .tex document where I am inserting code from files using `\lstinputlisting` and also ones where I am inserting handwritten snippets of code using `\begin{lstlisting}..\end{lstlisting}`.

I want the inserted code (inserted in any/both of the above ways) to have a grey background.
I found this answer - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177019/193728 which offers a solution, but there seems to be additional grey space(as border?) around the code, especially at the top and bottom.

Here is an example -
[image: example extra grey space]

How do I avoid this?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177019/81639 basically solves your problem, you only have to modify margins in the arguments of mdframed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings} %code extracts
\usepackage{xcolor} %custom colours
\usepackage{mdframed} %nice frames

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95} %the shade of grey that stack exchange uses

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=light-gray, roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, innerleftmargin=1, innertopmargin=1,innerbottommargin=1, outerlinewidth=1, linecolor=light-gray]
\begin{lstlisting}
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
      printf("Hello world!\n");
      return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}


\end{document}
```